# How can i view the Created Date and the Owner of the Field in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, field, owner, datecreated

I am working on Azure DevOps and I know little about the product. I want to view the field history when it is created and by whom it is created and last modified. 
I have gone through a couple of things in docs but it didn't help me.

**Research up till Now**

It shows me the fields but no information other than when I clicked on fields it gives me an option to delete the field.

Path
 Organization Setting > Process > Fields

Comment: @Kevin thankyou bunch of mistakes

Comment: You are most welcome. :-)

Comment: can you help me with this issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot.  I use the product but I have never tried to do what you are needing to do. Sorry.  :-(

Comment: please tag anyone if you know who came across this @KevinLaBranche

Comment: It is a bit unclear what info you want to get. Are you looking for the revision history of the work item type definition (ie. who added this custom field to the User Story type and when?), or are you looking for revision history of the values in the field for any given user story? (ie. when did Nichole change the value of this field to "true"?)

Comment: who added this custom field and when he/she added this custom field I am talking about the fields not the records @JoshGust

Comment: Unfortunately this functionality doesn't seem to exist. Perhaps adding a feature request to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) will gain enough support for it to be implemented.

Comment: Hi, what about Leo's answer which included the updated content? Does it is help for you? If yes, you can accept it. But if you still facing any other issue, feel free to leave comment there:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i view the Created Date and the Owner of the Field in Azure DevOps

Indeed, there is no such out of box way to get the Created Date and the Owner of the Field.

As a workaround, we could add a custom field in our custom process and set the value to **1** when the field is defined with a value. For example, I create a `MyCustomFiled` field and add rule to set the `MyCustomFiled` to 1 if the target field is defined:

[image]

[image]

In this case, when the target field is created by some one, our custom filed will be set with value **1**.

Next, we create a query with following Filters:

[image]

Now, we could get the Created Date and the Owner of the Field.

**Update:**

> what about the fields that are already created?

For this situation, we could query workitems whose fields have been modified according to the opposite conditions, for example, the Description field:

[image]

If this workaround still not work for you, you could try to use REST API [Revisions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get all the history for one workitem, use scripts to filter the revision about the specify field, then loop through all the workitems.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions/{revisionNumber}?api-version=5.1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
https://dev.azure.com/*org*/*project*/_workitems/assignedtome/
```

or simply click the work items in the left navigation

Select Column Options

Add Created Date